# Best way to check if a string contains consecutive substring?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to find the best way to check if a string has consecutive appearances of a particular substring. returning a boolean value e.g. only returning True if the whole string sits next to itself inside the string. Some example test cases:

```
consecutive_checker(string='blaablaa', substring = 'a')
>>> True

consecutive_checker(string='blaablaa', substring = 'aa')
>>> False

consecutive_checker(string='blaablaa', substring = 'blaa')
>>> True

consecutive_checker(string='blaablaa', substring = 'baa')
>>> False
```

### My Apporach:

```
def consecutive_checker(string='blaablaa', substr = 'blaa'):
    count = string.count(substr)
    if count > 1:
        for sidx in range(len(string) - len(substr)+1):
            for ssidx in range(len(substr)+1):
                if string[sidx:sidx+ssidx] == string[sidx+ssidx:sidx+ssidx*2] == substr:
                    return True
    return False
```

Here for efficiency (If its not fairly obvious):

1. It only proceeds if substring is appeared atleast twice.
2. Lengthwise it cherrypicks indices
3. Returns as soon as consecutive substrings are found

So I was thinking how I can improve it even further. Seems like builtin `count()` function although very efficient is iterating whole string. It could be a point of improvement but I cannot totally avoid this as I used it as my safety net to only iterate when needed. Similarly three ugly checks and dual for loops does not give off a efficiency vibe. So how can I improve it even more? Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're really overcomplicating this. Just double the substring and check if that appears in the string.

```
def consecutive_checker(string, substr):
    return substr*2 in string
```

Comment: I see! Infact it would be better to say I oversee ;) Besides it would be better to use `substr*2` as it would be scalable. Incase there are definite number of consecutive substr duplications to be found.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the `.find()` function which returns the first index of the argument (substring) passed. For the case when it does not find it, it will return `-1`.

```
>>> string = 'blaablaa'
>>> string.find('aa'*2)
-1
>>> string.find('blaa'*2)
0
```